# Handling Data Objects in ReactElements

Tags: arrays, reactjs, array-map

I'm retrieving the following Data Object from an API

```
channels: [{
  label: 'X',
  key: 'topic',
  count: 3,
  messages: {
    '0': {
      foo: 'X',
    },
    '1': {
      foo: 'X',
    },
    '2': {
      foo: 'X',
  },
},]
```

Now I need to itereate over the messages that are within the object to return the variable "foo". Since there can be multiple channels and each channel can have multiple messages my approach is:

```
channels.map(channel => channel.messages.map(message => message.foo)
```

React prints the error "TypeError: channel.messages.map is not a function" instead. I guess the problem is that I'm using the Map-Function on an object and not an actual array but I couldn't figure out how to solve that problem.

I'm thankful for any advice.

Comment: `channels.flatMap(channel => Object.values(channel.messages).flatMap(o => Object.keys(o)))`

Comment: If messages are guaranteed to be dense, you can transform them into a real Array as simple as `Object.values(channel.messages)`.

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
channels.map(channel => channel.messages.map(message => message.foo)
```

to

```
channels.map(channel => Object.values(channel.messages).map(message => message.foo)
```

and it worked. Thanks to raina77ow
See the definition of Object.values() on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)